# Powershell how to change the defaultrunspace set disableformatupdates false

Tags: powershell, runspace

I've a need to change the "DisableFormatUpdates" session state value within my powershell.  I've figured out how to retrieve the initial session state:

`[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace.InitialSessionState`

> DisableFormatUpdates          : True

Which returns the value as expected.

However I don't understand how to set this value to False, so that I can complete an import of a module.   It appears that the runspace is being set by SMA, but I need to reset this value for a module that we're required to load.

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm definitely out of my element on setting this within the context of my powershell workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the sessionstate object and then set the property to `$true` or `$false`

```
PS C:\> $sessionstate = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
PS C:\> $sessionstate.DisableFormatUpdates = $true
PS C:\> $sessionstate.DisableFormatUpdates
True
PS C:\> $sessionstate.DisableFormatUpdates = $false
PS C:\> $sessionstate.DisableFormatUpdates
False
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  I did in fact figure this out after much annoyance.  I assumed it had to be a boolean set in C# to set the value and I was wrong.   Much appreciated!